# TableHeadings align to the right

Tags: output-formatting

Is there away to get `TableHeadings` align to the `Right` instead of the default to the `Left`? For example, for

```
TableForm[{{1}, {3}}, TableHeadings->{{"t111111", "t2"}, {"Values"}}]
```

is there a way to have `t111111` and `t2` align to the right?

Comment: you meant "... instead of default to the _left_"?

Comment: @kguler Thanks! Just edited again

Comment: Related: "[`TableForm` with `TableHeadings` aligned to `Left` but the content of table aligned to `Right`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6242080/590388)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure hope there is an easier way than the following

```
tf = TableForm[{{1}, {3}}, TableHeadings -> {{"t111111", "t2"}, {"Values"}}]
```

[image]

```
RawBoxes[ToBoxes@tf /. HoldPattern[ColumnAlignments -> _]:>(ColumnAlignments -> {Right, Left})]
```

[image]

```
tf = TableForm[{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}},TableHeadings->{{"t111111","t2"},{"Val1", "Val2", "Val3"}}];

RawBoxes[ToBoxes@tf /. HoldPattern[ColumnAlignments -> _]:>(ColumnAlignments -> {Right, Center})]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
leftpad[list_] :=
 With[{blanks = StringJoin /@ Map[Table[" ", {#}] &, Max[#] - # &[StringLength /@ list]]},
  Map[StringJoin[blanks[[#]], list[[#]]] &, Range @ Length @ list]]

keys = {"a", "abcd" , "abc", "ab"};
vals = Range @ 4;

TableForm[List /@ vals, TableHeadings -> {leftpad @ keys, {"Values"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know if you realize this, but you can edit your deleted answers and undelete them instead of posting new ones.

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks. I will do that in the future :)